# Insert into from temp table - creating too many rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am bulk importing CSV file into a temporary table and then inserting the rows into the target table if they do not already exists.

When I start the process, my table has the following values

VECH01 **AAA** 111
VECH01 **BBB** 222
VECH01 **CCC** 333
VECH02 **AAA** 111
VECH02 **BBB** 222
VECH02 **CCC** 333

When I import a CSV file with these values:

VECH01|DDD|444
VECH01|DDD|555
VECH02|CCC|XXX

The 1st row is imported VECH01 DDD is not in the database.
**OK**

The 2nd row is imported but VECH01 DDD is already in the database, it was imported in the previous insert.
**NOT OK**

The 3rd row is not imported because VECH02 CCC already exists in the database.
**OK**

```
CREATE TABLE #csv 
(
 CarRedbookCode nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
 AccessoryCode nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
 AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
)

DECLARE @SqlStatement nvarchar(4000)
SET @SqlStatement =
'
BULK INSERT #csv
 FROM ''' + @FileName + '''
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' 
    )
'
EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement

INSERT INTO  MapRedbookAccessory (CarRedbookCodeAccessoryCode, CarRedbookCode,     AccessoryCode, AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral) 
 select 
  src.CarRedbookCode + src.AccessoryCode
 , src.CarRedbookCode
 , src.AccessoryCode
 , src.AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral 
 from
  #csv src
 left join
  MapRedbookAccessory dst on dst.CarRedbookCodeAccessoryCode = src.CarRedbookCode + src.AccessoryCode
 where
  dst.CarRedbookCodeAccessoryCode is null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the INSERT statement does not process the rows individually.  There might be a better way to do this, but you can use the ROW_NUMBER function to insert only the first row for each code/accessory:

```
INSERT INTO  MapRedbookAccessory (CarRedbookCodeAccessoryCode, CarRedbookCode,     AccessoryCode, AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral) 
 select 
  src.CarRedbookCode + src.AccessoryCode
 , src.CarRedbookCode
 , src.AccessoryCode
 , src.AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral 
 from
 (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarRedbookCode, AccessoryCode ORDER BY AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral) AS row
    from #csv) src
 left join
  MapRedbookAccessory dst on dst.CarRedbookCodeAccessoryCode = src.CarRedbookCode + src.AccessoryCode
 where
  dst.CarRedbookCodeAccessoryCode is null
  and src.row = 1
```

You can change the `ORDER BY` depending on which AccessoryCodeAutoGeneral you want to insert if there are multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample CSV import data, the two DDD rows have different numeric values after them which would make them different rows. So VECH01|DDD *should* be inserted twice. Is that correct, or is the sample data incorrect?

Comment: The sample data is correct, what should happen is that the 1st row with VECH01|DDD|444 should be inserted and the 2nd row VECH01|DDD|555 should be discarded, only the Redbook Code (Vech01) and Accessory Code (DDD) are part of the key, apparently I can get duplicate keys in the CSV file, but I only want to insert the first occurence and discard any others.